# View instance from RemoteViews

Tags: android, view, instance, android-appwidget

How can I get `View` instance from `RemoteViews` ? There are `RemoteViews.reapply` and `RemoteViews.apply` API functions , but I don't know how to use them.

Comment: Please describe where and how you are trying to "get View instance from RemoteViews". Are you writing your own home screen?

Comment: No, I am writing it in AppwidgetProvider. (actually class that extends AppwidgetProvider)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are the one creating the `RemoteViews` to hand to something else -- as is the case with an `AppWidgetProvider` -- you cannot "get View instance from RemoteViews". The `View` hierarchy created from your `RemoteViews` is created in a different process than your own, and so you do not have direct access to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like:

```
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_anything, "Anytext");
```